# Newsfeed not showing up on personal sites

Tags: 2013, my-site, newsfeed

I have MySites set up and Newsfeed enabled thru the User Profile Service App, but on any given user profile, the newsfeed doesn't show up. I don't mean the common issue of seeing the newsfeed but no activites, there's just plain no newsfeed:

[image]

Any ideas what's going on here and how to get the newsfeed to show up?

Comment: Check the users profile in UPS, make sure the `Personal Site Capabilities` is `14` and nothing else. I had this problem with a user once (instead of the normal "Something went wrong" on the actual Newsfeed page)

Comment: Also make sure the user actually has a mysite (so this is not just the shared "person.aspx" page)

Comment: @RobertLindgren Thanks for the input Robert. I see the field "Personal Site Capabilities" reads `0` actually. Additionally, I see that a personal site goes to the person.aspx site, not the actual personal site. Any ideas how to rectify these two issues?

Comment: Try updating the 0 to 14 first, if you are lucky that will resolve your issue

Comment: @RobertLindgren We have hundreds of user profiles, hopefully we don't have to do that manually for every one of them? Plus when I edit that field and try to save, I just get "An error occurred trying to save your profile."

Comment: Here's a script for automating it: http://blogs.technet.com/b/vinitt/archive/2013/04/23/newsfeed-error-a-required-sharepoint-feature-is-not-enabled-sharepoint-2013-fba-site.aspx but if you get errors when saving it looks like you have a deeper error! Look in the ULS logs for details about the error,

Comment: @RobertLindgren I don't get a correlation ID... what's the best way of going about finding this error in the ULS logs?

Comment: You could use ULSViewer, where it appends from the log files in real time. So you can start that up and the trigger the error. Just a thought though, your error could be caused by the profile missing value in a required property

Comment: @RobertLindgren I was able to get that field updated and Newsfeed is now showing up on the sidebar, but clicking it just goes to "Default.aspx" with "We're almost ready!" and I still don't see a newsfeed

Comment: That could take some time though, give it 10 minutes or so. If not working then you might need to remove this users mysite, and empty "feed provider id" and "personal site URL" (again, don't know exact names but something like that). The next time you try to go to your mysite it should get recreated

Comment: @RobertLindgren Strange, my personal profile seems to be one of the only ones that doesn't even have a site created to begin with. Not sure why it won't create.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16260/discussion-between-robert-lindgren-and-tnw).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The result of our chat:**

This error can be due to a number of things.

- Check that the users Personal site collection is actually created:

  - If so,

    1. Make sure the `Personal Site Capabilities` on the users profile (in the UPS) is `14`.
    2. If that does not help, delete the users Personal site collection (possible data loss) and empty the values for `Personal Site` and `Feed service provider defined identifier`. The next time the user tries to reach their Personal Site, SharePoint will try to recreate it.
  - If not so,

    1. Search the ULS -logs for a similar entry like this

       > "Skipping creation of personal site from MySitePersonalSiteUpgradeOnNavigationWebPart::CreatePersonalSite() because one or more of the creation criteria has not been met. [SPWeb Url=......../Person.aspx?accountname=(User Name )] htt://......./Person.aspx?accountname=username]Self-Service Site Creation == True Can Create Personal Site == False Is user licensed == False Storage&Social UPA Permission == True Site or Page or Web Part is in design mode == False"

       As you can see, the last part gives you some useful information!
    2. If `Self-Service Site Creation == False`, [make sure you have a wildcard managed path created](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624362(v=office.15).aspx#wildcardpath) for the Personal Sites in the MySite web application, also [you must make sure you have configured SSSC correctly](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624362(v=office.15).aspx#enableselfsvc)
    3. If `Is user licensed == False`, you seem to have a [license problem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219627.aspx), giving you two options.

       - License the users (PowerShell):

         ```
         Get-SPUserLicense
         $a = New-SPUserLicenseMapping -SecurityGroup <yoursecuritygroup> –License Enterprise
         $a | Add-SPUserLicenseMapping
         Enable-SPUserLicensing
         ```
       - Disable licensing (PowerShell):

         ```
         Disable-SPUserLicensing
         ```

If you do not find a log entry like the one above, you can try to run the creation job manually. It is a timer job named `My Site Instantiation Interactive Request Queue`, also make sure that this job is scheduled to run regularly (default is every minute).

If you are setting up MySite for the first time, you can follow Microsoft's guide [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624362(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you apply a custom master page on your personal site collection, maybe you hid the newsfeed `<div>` accidentally.